# pushing persistent postgres data to git with docker

Tags: git, postgresql, api, docker, backend

I am currently using postgres with Docker and I have my persistent data shared as a volume on my hard drive. Since I am working in a team, I want to push those data into a git repository so that others can build the docker container as well and use the current postgres data.

However this shared volume folder is pretty big (more than 50mb for just one table) and I don't think it's a good idea to push all those binary files onto a git repository.

What is the best workflow to use postgres data within Docker, so that we can work in a team with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is probably too open-ended to have a definite answer, notably as you ask "what is the best workflow", which might be viewed as opinion-based.

However, I give below a few pointers you may be interested in as they highlight possible solutions for your goal.

On the Git side:

- [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/)
- [Git-annex](https://git-annex.branchable.com/)

(Both tools allow one to version-control large repositories (beyond 1GB or so) without paying the performance penalty that would occur if directly committing large files using vanilla Git.)

Otherwise, on the Docker side:

- An interesting blog article [How to Back Up Your Data Volumes to Docker Hub](https://dzone.com/articles/docker-backup-your-data-volumes-to-docker-hub).